# mongodb select using association

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections, user_logs and users, user_logs documents have user_id field so I need some data from user_logs but in the same query I want to check if some other field from user related to the current user_log is empty. How should I do this?

Comment: what do you want to do when the fields are empty? add sample data would help your question more clear

Comment: MongoDB does not do joins. If you want information from two collections you must do at least two queries. For more help than that, we need to see sample documents and a description of what exactly you are trying to query for.

Answer (score 0):

A query can only access one collection at a time. Mongodb doesn't support joins. 
They that's why they recommend that you embed the referenced data inside the document.
If the logs documents for each user isn't too big, then you can change the embed that info inside the user collection.
Giving you something like this.

#### Embedded User Collection:

```
{
    user_id : "uid1",
    logs : [
        { message : "Error: System shutdown", date : "2014-11-11" },
        { message : "Error: System shutdown", date : "2014-11-13" }
    ]
}
```

However, if you want to keep your current structure then you're going to have to perform two queries to find related info between the `users` and `user_logs` collections.

#### Example

```
db.user_logs.insert([
    { _id : "ul1", log : "code 1", user_id : "u1" },
    { _id : "ul2", log : "code 2", user_id : "u1" }
]);
db.users.insert([
    { _id : "u1", name : "bob", user_logs_id : "ul1" },
    { _id : "u2", name : "smith", user_logs_id : "ul2" }
]);

var userId = db.user_logs.findOne({}).user_id;
db.users.findOne({ _id : userId })
//outputs
{ "_id" : "u1", "name" : "bob", "user_logs_id" : "ul1" }
```